# (Laravel) Doubts concerning Mass Assignment protection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, mass-assignment

I'm developing a website with several contents, including a blog, and I've come up to some doubts concerning mass assignment protection.

When I'm posting a comment on a blog article, I suppose the 'fillable' fields would be the comment's body, the article id and the parent_comment_id (optional and used only for replies to a comment), but when I came up to

```
ArticleComment::create([
            'author_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'body' => $request->input('body'),
            'article_id' => $request->input('article_id'),
            'parent_comment_id' => $request->input('parent_comment_id')
        ]);
```

I found out that even the author_id field should be mass-assignable in order to have it persisted in the database (and not to get a foreign key failure).
The only alternative I found would be assembling the comment from a new instance and saving it:

```
$comment = new App\ArticleComment();
$comment->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
$comment->body = $request->input('body');
$comment->article_id = $request->input('article_id');
$comment->parent_comment_id = $request->input('parent_comment_id');
$comment->save()
```

but in this case there would be no need to have any 'fillable' field, because this way does not generate any mass-assignment exception.

I know that mass-assignment is supposed to prevent malicious data alteration through a post request, but I don't really get, for example, how would anybody modify the author_id in row 2 since it comes from Auth and not from input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case, you would use `new ArticleComment($request->input())` or `$comment->fill($request->input())` to assign the user-enterable data, then assign the id's or non-user editable data (in your case, the `author_id`) separately.

```
$comment = new App\ArticleComment($request->input());
$comment->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
$comment->save()
```

This would prevent users from POSTing a form with author_id as a field, but still allows you to quickly assign the user fields, without having to list them everywhere you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, no one will be able to modify it. However, what if you wanted to assign something like this?

```
ArticleComment::create($request->all());
```

Now the fields **can** be modified. That is what Mass Assignement is meant to protect against.